# Alternate to Validic Framework

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hybrid-mobile-app

We use Validic API in mobile application to connect to bluetooth devices to read bp measurements from bp monitor device and weight measurements from weight scales. Is there any alternate API framework similar to validic which does the same job.

How complex it is to write our custom API for native mobile applications?

Thanks,

Comment: This depends on how well the services and characteristics of your BLE device are documented. If you don't know what kind of data to send to which characteristic this becomes a very tedious if not impossible task

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Thank you for the response. Is there any other API from VivifyHealth or HumanAPI or any other competitors which does the job as connecting to bluetooth monitor devices (BP, Glucometer, Weight Scale etc) and read the readings, communicate back to mobile application?

Comment: I've never used the validic framework and I am not aware of any other library that does what you need.